# WPF Animation - Why Can't "By" have a negitive value?

Tags: wpf, animation

I am poking around the animation in WPF and I am confused.  For RectAnimation, By cannot be negative for height and width.

So, if you use the "By" keyword, rectangles can only grow (instead of "To")?

Here is some example code:

```
<Page  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="LemonChiffon">
      <Path.Data>
        <RectangleGeometry x:Name="myRectangleGeometry" Rect="0,200,100,100" />

      </Path.Data>
      <Path.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard> 
              <!-- Animate the Rect property of the RectangleGeometry
                   which causes the rectangle to animate postion and size. -->
              <RectAnimation
              Storyboard.TargetName="myRectangleGeometry"
              Storyboard.TargetProperty ="Rect"
              Duration="0:0:2" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" 
              From="0,0,100,100"
              By="600,50,200,-50" />
                               ^
            </Storyboard>      |
          </BeginStoryboard>   |
        </EventTrigger>        |
      </Path.Triggers>         |
    </Path>                    |
  </StackPanel>                |
</Page>                        |
                               |
This returns an error, but only if it is negative.
```

Comment: Lol, downvote with no comment.  You got to love it when people are chicken.

Comment: +1 offset... someone downvoted me on it too for some reason...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually defining a rectangle in the `By` property of the RectAnimation object. A rectangle cannot be created with negative sizes.

`By="x,y,Width,Height"`

What you're probably wanting to do can be accomplished using the `To` property instead:

`To="600,50,300,50"`

Comment: I knew about the To property, but what if you want to shrink by a relative amount?

Comment: I think that's something that Microsoft in their infinite wisdom may have not thought of when they set that up... Either way, even if you're working from code and not from markup, if you need to shrink a rectangle, you'll need to do the appropriate math and use the `To` property instead of the `By` property.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like it either... I'd like to make shapes in general with negative sizes (aka flipped), but it's just not possible.

Comment: If you touch your answer I will up vote it (I can't because it says it is too old unless the answer is edited)

Comment: The System.Windows.Rect.Inflate(Rect,double,double) overload should provide all the utility you need to use the To property here.